# How to use OUT Parameters in LINQ

Tags: c#, stored-procedures, linq-to-sql

My stored procedure use one out parameters. I want to use that out parameters in My MVC application.
Can I know how can I use out parameters in LINQ.
What I am doing

```
[global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.FunctionAttribute(Name="dbo.Usp_Insert_Id")]
public int Usp_Insert_Id(
    [global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ParameterAttribute(Name="EmpID", DbType="Int")]
    System.Nullable<int> EmpID)
{
    IExecuteResult result =
       this.ExecuteMethodCall(
            this,
            ((MethodInfo)(MethodInfo.GetCurrentMethod())),
            EmpID);
    return ((int)(result.ReturnValue));
}
```

in the controller I’m using

```
int output = 0;
output = dataContext.Usp_Insert_Id(Id,ref output);
```

My Stored Procedure for this is

```sql
create procedure Usp_Insert_Id ( @Id
int, @Return int out ) as insert into
Emplyee(ID,Date_TIME,Status)
values (@Id,GETDATE(),1)

select @Return=SCOPE_IDENTITY()
```

tell me what I’m doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Check good article by ScottGU**
[image]

[image]

[LINQ to SQL (Part 6 - Retrieving Data Using Stored Procedures)](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/08/16/linq-to-sql-part-6-retrieving-data-using-stored-procedures.aspx)

Ans for you :

[LINQ and StoredProcedure output Parameter](http://forums.asp.net/t/1238073.aspx)

Comment: Please check the question i have updated?? Please tell me what i m doing wrong?

Comment: The method or operation is not implemented.

Comment: hey follow the scottgu article step by step and check again

Comment: first of all remove that procedure... and than try

Comment: i m not getting the required result now i have create new stored procedure for this. Please check where i m wrong?

Comment: i m not able to get the result is there any other way to return value from stored procedure using linq?? If yes then please tell me that